# How do I create a hash of hashes inside of a .each in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm working on a Rails application that tracks different events and their statuses.

Here's my `Status` model:

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :value

  has_many :events
end
```

There is an interface to add additional status types.

My `Event` model looks like this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :status_id

  belongs_to :status

  class << self
    Status.all.each do |status|
      define_method(status.value.downcase) do
        send("where", :status_id => Status.find_by_value(status.value.downcase))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So for example I have three different status values: `Outage`, `Slow`, `Error`, etc.

With this I can do:

```
Event.outage
```

or:

```
Event.slow
```

and I'll get back an `ActiveRecord::Relation` of all events with that status. This works as expected.

I have a view that generates some graphs dynamically using [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com). Here's my view code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function () {
    new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: { renderTo: 'events_chart' },
        title: { text: '' },
        xAxis: { type: 'datetime' },
        yAxis: {
          title: { text: 'Event Count' },
          min: 0,
          tickInterval: 1
        },
        series:[
              <% { "Events" => Event,
                   "Outages" => Event.outage, 
                   "Slowdowns" => Event.slow, 
                   "Errors" => Event.error,
                   "Restarts" => Event.restart }.each do |name, event| %>
            {
              name: "<%= name %>",
              pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
              pointStart: <%= @start_date.to_time.to_i * 1000 %>,
              pointEnd: <%= @end_date.to_time.to_i * 1000 %>,
              data: <%= (@start_date..@end_date).map { |date| event.reported_on(date).count}.inspect %>
            },
            <% end %>]
          });
        });
</script>

<div id="events_chart"></div>
```

I'd like to generate this hash dynamically with a list of `Status` types from the database:

```
<% { 
     "Outage" => Event.outage, 
     "Slow" => Event.slow, 
     "Error" => Event.error,
     "Restart" => Event.restart }.each do |name, event|
%>
```

using something like this:

```
hash = Status.all.each do |status|
  hash.merge("#{status.value}" => Event) ||= {}
end
```

I want to call `each` on the hash to generate my charts. This doesn't give me a hash though, it gives me an `Array`, just like `Status.all` would by itself.

Comment: It's not necessary to tell us how much you like Stack Overflow. Using it and asking questions, then answering them when its your time, is thanks enough. Consider Stack Overflow to be like Wikipedia, where every question is an article, followed by answers attempting to find solutions to everyday developer's problems. Keep your question succinct and accurately describe the problem you've encountered; Consider the things you'd need to know to solve the problem if someone else asked it, and put only those in. You did pretty well for your first question, and welcome to SO!

Comment: Have a look at `Hash.[]`. It can give a hash from array(nested or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it, with [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) and [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
hash = Status.select(:value).each_with_object({}) do |s, h|
  h[s.value.upcase] = Event.send s.value.downcase
end
```

Comment: Brilliant! I had to change it to this : |s, h| to get it to work. But that fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @jamesgifford I'm glad you caught that. I've edited the answer.